# Tab bar disappearing when drilling down through navigation controller

Tags: iphone, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, storyboard

I've setup an App that has a Tab Bar controller as a screen in a navigation controller using the storyboard. I can navigate to it fine, but when I start drilling down through screens in one of the tabs, the tab bar disappears. If I navigate back to the first screen the tab bar is supposed to be on, the tab bar will reappear, but I would prefer if it was visible on the child screens. Is this possible or do the two view controllers just not play well together?

Answer (score 0):

The tab bar controller always needs to be the root view controller. You can't put it INSIDE a navigation controller.

Even if it was possible, it wouldn't be good user interaction. What is it you're trying to do exactly (functional)?

I think what you want is to place the navigation controller as the first tab inside the tab bar controller instead.  (not the other way around like you're describing)

Comment: Its for a menu app, so all the subsequent screens are based off the choice of a restaurant on the first page. Didn't seem to make sense to have a series of tabs available that won't have any information unless you make a choice on the first tab.

Answer (score 0):

```
                    - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
                    {

        MenuViewController * menuViewController=[[[MenuViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MenuViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil] autorelease];

menuViewController.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed=YES;
        //menuViewController You can have your option here 


                     UINavigationController * navigationController;
                     UINavigationController * navigationController2;
                     UINavigationController * navigationController3;

                    viewController1 = [[[FirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FirstViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil] autorelease];



                            viewController2 = [[[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil] autorelease];


     navigationController=[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController1];

            navigationController2=[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController2];

            navigationController3=[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:menuViewController];



               UITabBarController   * tabBarController = [[[UITabBarController alloc] init] autorelease];
                        self.tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:menuViewController,navigationControllerFirst, viewController2, nil];


                        //self.tabBarController.tabBar.tintColor=[UIColor orangeColor];
                        self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;


                        [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

                return true;
                }
```

Comment: This creates two navigation controllers in a tab bar controller. I need to display options to the user before the tab bar controller is displayed.

Comment: @ErrantConstruct I have edited the code according to your message/need. This will help you surely.Thanks :)